# How to return value from a SDK request without a callback

Tags: javascript, sdk, callback

In the abstract below, I'm using an SDK which has one SendRequests class which returns the retrieved objects to a callback method.

```
    getThumbnail : function(imageId){
            var request = new SDK.ImageRequest();
            request.ImageId = imageId;

            SDK.SendRequests([request], callback);
    }
```

But, what if I don't want to use a callback method and instead want to be able to return the value directly to the caller?  For example:

```
    var thumbnail = model.getThumbnail(12345);
```

Thanks!

Comment: what sdk is it? does it have a sync version?

Comment: See the **Related** sidebar, there are several answers explaining that you can't generally do this, and showing how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

That's just the nature of javascript. You could wrap it and return a promise.